# Как узнать что сайт просматривают на телевизоре?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Хочу задать условия, при котором скрипт на телевизоре не будет выполнятся,
но браузеры на телевизоре будто не видят эти условия, и в любом случае скрипт срабатывает.
На обычных браузерах все работает хорошо (пробовал на разных мониторах)

Сейчас это выглядит так -

```
<script th:src="@{/resources/js/snowfall.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.innerWidth < 2560) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).snowfall({
                collection: '.box,ul',
                flakeCount: 100
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Пробовал разные условия :

```
$(document).width ,
$(window).width ,
window.width.
```

Буду благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достоверно это никак узнать нельзя. На телевизоре может работать обычный браузер с любым разрешением. Например браузер на 1920 px на телевизоре 4K. Также к телевизору может быть приставка с любой логикой или компьютер. Телевизор никак не сообщает браузеру о том, что он телевизор. Если даже логика с шириной экрана сработает, небольшой монитор 4K будет при такой логике считаться телевизором.